# OpenSSH is slow over OpenVPN

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, openvpn, openssh

I have 2 PCs [server, client] running Arch Linux (everything up-to-date) and using OpenVPN to connect to a corporate LAN since the server doesn't have a public IP address; however, when I run `ssh $IP_ADDRESS`, I get a very slow session, waiting seconds for typed content to appear on the screen:

- `sshd_config`: I've tried toggling `UseDNS` and `GSSAPIAuthentication`, but it doesn't help

  ```
  Port 50200
  PermitRootLogin yes
  AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
  ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
  GSSAPIAuthentication no
  UsePAM yes
  AllowTcpForwarding yes
  ClientAliveInterval 60
  Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server
  UseDNS No
  ```

These work flawlessly:

- **SCP:** takes quite long to start, but transfers files with good speed at ~23MB/s (seems to be my provider limit)
- **RDP:** runs without delays using Remmina on the client / `xrdp`, `xorgxrdp` (aur) on the server
- **LAN SSH:** works fine without OpenVPN when connecting via `ssh $IP_ADDRESS`

Comment: You have a problem with too much latency. Nothing much you can do about that. Maybe try mosh (mobile shell). You can also try to find the network link that is to blame.

Comment: No one can diagnose the issue without the OpenVPN server and client configs _(many folks often have sub-optimal OpenVPN configurations that slow throughput and affect latency)_, and please also add whether the client's and server's CPUs support AES-NI. Once symbols appear in the terminal, does the lag still persist?